# Instagram API - Cannot Update Client - "Sorry, an error occurred while processing this request."

Tags: instagram

I'm trying to set up various Instagram clients to use with website integration.  I must say that I am extremely disappointed in the quality of the Instagram developer documentation, and their API has some seriously annoying aspects to it.

That being said, when I try to update one any of my clients (under any of three accounts), I get the following error (in a non-styled, blank page):

```
Sorry, an error occurred while processing this request.
```

What gives?  I was able to update a few of my clients, but then started getting this error.

Also, why does Instagram make it nearly impossible to create more than five clients?  I need more than this to cover all of the environments that the website(s) run in, so I've been forced to create multiple Instagram accounts for each site...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Instagram's API (or at least the part relating to adding/editing clients) was down.  I guess I'll mark this as answered, but I really wish Instagram would offer better documentation/support...